# Select all Excel cells that do not contain e-mail addresses

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010. How can I select all cells that **aren't** e-mail addresses? I want to delete them and keep only the cells that validate to e-mail addresses.

Comment: Nice edit, @Lord T. Nadeen, your first question [was improved by the community](http://superuser.com/posts/291867/revisions) as well. Please use that as feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validating email addresses is a black hole. And even if you were able to determine that validity of the email, you still won't know if it's a working email, or even that person's email (they may have entered someone else's address).

If you still want to do a basic test of syntax the you can go into VBA (may require enabling on the Developer tab on the ribbon) and set a reference to "Microsoft VBSript Regular Expressions 5.5", create a new module and enter this code (I am not skilled in RegEx so I got it from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses), you can get other RegExs at [FightingForALostCause](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) or a full descussion at [Regular-Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)):

```
Public Function CheckEmailSyntax(ByVal Email As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$"
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    CheckEmailSyntax = regex.Test(Email)
End Function
```

Then in your project enter something like `=CheckEmailSyntax(A1)`. It will return `TRUE` for the good ones and `FALSE` for the bad ones. Sort both columns by the T/F column and delete the FALSE ones. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. But for example, surely the plus-character [is used quite a lot](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12096) in email addresses nowadays. So: beware for false negatives when using such simple regex.

Comment: @Arjan Very true. I added links to other (perhaps better?) regexs. The problem remains as I warned, you still don't know if all the 'good' emails are in use, and it they are for the person you think.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Go to *Editing* on the home ribbon.
2. Click *Find and Select*.
3. Enter *@* in *Find what:*.
4. Click *Find All*.
5. In the results, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select entire group in the results.
6. Click *Copy* on the home ribbon.
7. Paste to a new column.

Comment: +1 those simple tricks are stunning even after years. Ok, it has some downsides. For example what if non-mail cells have a @ char. Or you want all mail cells in a single target column. But nevertheless, this is good.

Answer (score -2):

I would use the Find & Select/Data Validation.

- On the Home tab, go to the Editing Group.
- Choose "Find & Select"
- Choose Go to Special
- Choose Data Validation
- Choose Same or All
- Click OK

The cells that contain data validation will be highlighted.

Comment: no i dont want that , i dont want a cell that contains a data validation , i want to select all the cells that doesn't match to an email pattern

Comment: -1 didnt address actual question.